# Cannot send attachments or embedds with Discord API

Tags: typescript, api, discord, deno

I need help with an error about Attachments in the Discord API.

It is responding to the ApplicationCommandType of the slash command in serverless, but it succeeds with Content only, but not with Content but with embedds and attachments.
(I don't even know how to find out more about this error.)

I have no idea what is wrong and would appreciate your help.

I am using deno environment with discord-api-types edited for deno. discord.js is not used.

```
import {
  APIApplicationCommandInteraction,
  APIInteractionResponse,
  InteractionResponseType,
  APIAttachment,
  APIEmbed
} from "../lib/discord-api-types/payloads/index.ts";

import { Snowflake } from "../lib/discord-api-types/globals.ts";

import { DiscordSnowflake as sf } from "../lib/snowflake/DiscordSnowflake.ts";

export const onApplicationCommand = (
  interaction: APIApplicationCommandInteraction
) => {
  let res: APIInteractionResponse = {
    type: InteractionResponseType.ChannelMessageWithSource,
    data: {
      // Success!!
      content: "hello"

      // Some Error
      // embeds: [
      //   {url: "https://media.valorant-api.com/weaponskinlevels/d6b75f1b-409b-bae9-d378-d3adf04a3ca9/displayicon.png"} as APIEmbed
      // ]

      // Some Error
      // attachments: [
      //   {
      //     id: sf.generate().toString() as Snowflake,
      //     filename: "displayicon.png",
      //     content_type: "image/png",
      //     size: 56056,
      //     url: "https://media.valorant-api.com/weaponskinlevels/d6b75f1b-409b-bae9-d378-d3adf04a3ca9/displayicon.png",
      //     proxy_url: "https://media.valorant-api.com/weaponskinlevels/d6b75f1b-409b-bae9-d378-d3adf04a3ca9/displayicon.png",
      //   } as APIAttachment,
      // ],
    },
  };

  return res;
};
```

I edited discord-api-types to use type definitions.
I looked on github for a use of attachment, but it was using discord.js and was not helpful.
I don't know what the discord error is after sending a response, so I need to know how to find out. I couldn't figure out how to do this either.

Comment: The `url` parameter of an embed is the `title` link. If you want an image, use `image` and pass in the image url. That might be the issue with the embed.